# The specified module could not be found. Postgres 15.2 with timescale 2.10.3

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, postgresql-15

I am trying to add timescaledb extension in my postgres 15.2 with timescale 2.10.3.

When I run the command

```
create extension if not exists timescaledb;
```

I get below message

> could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/lib/timescaledb-2.10.3.dll": The specified module could not be found.

On physically verifying, the file is present there.

Also tried copying files libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, still same error.

I have only postgres 15.2 in my system

Comment: maybe an issue because the path uses slashes (/) instead of backslashes (\\)?

Comment: That message is from postgres. I dont have any control over that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be known issue in windows(https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/5631)
I would prefer installing from source if you are running the postgres in local machine
Or use timescaledb docker image as below

```
 timescale:
    image: timescale/timescaledb
    container_name: timescale
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres      
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres      
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - timescale-data:/home/postgres/pgdata/data/
```

Please follow the steps below for installing from source
https://docs.timescale.com/self-hosted/latest/install/installation-source/

Let me know if you need any further help with the installation

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should find in your system two dlls `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` and copy both of them to Postgres **bin** folder.
I somehow found these dlls in my system just searching by name in `C:\Windows\System32` folder and they were found here (in your system the path can be different) `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iclsclient.inf_amd64_76523213b78d9046\lib`.
Then I copied and pasted them to **bin** folder and restarted Postgres windows service and everything started working well.
Thanks for the [Dependencies x64](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) I opened "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/lib/timescaledb-2.10.3.dll" there and saw missing dlls.